# Why is sendBroadcastAsUser(intent,userHandle) not working even with Device Owner in Android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, device-admin, device-owner

I have made my application as the device owner and have created another user. Now I want to broadcast from Primary user to another user using broadcastAsUser.

I have added the following permissions for this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>

UserManager userManager=(UserManager)getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE);
UserHandle userHandle=userManager.getUserForSerialNumber(serialNumber);
Intent intent=new Intent(action);
sendBroadcastAsUser(intent,userHandle);
```

Permission Denial: broadcast from com.sample.deviceadmintest asks to run as user 10 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

Am I missing anything?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason. Though the application is the device owner, it doesn't have the permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

The device owner still doesn't have all the permission that a system application has. Device owner application is not a system application.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more..so now how can I make this work ?